# Felxible term clouds

Tags: user-interaction, word-cloud

I have to implement dynamic term clouds. I need to let the users remove terms from clouds or assign them to from one cloud to another one. They should be also capable of merging or splitting clouds. Hence, the clouds should be completely dynamic in a way that the user has all kinds of freedom to manipulate them.
Is there any library in Java that could help me out? Is there any implementation already available for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I found an API that is free while in beta.
http://tagul.com/
Users can exclude certain words from the clouds, you can create custom shapes, and duplicate clouds. 
The clouds it generates have rollover effects and can be exported as graphics with transparent backgrounds.